# Problem after mysql-server installation I cant install any thing in ubuntu 12.04.1 now

Tags: installation, mysql

I'm not an advanced user of Linux and I tried to install work with database so I installed Mysql-server, I think I did same thing wrong so I get in trouble and now I cant install any thing 
and  this what I get when I use `apt-get -f install` :

```
root@me:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
  tinyca mailx
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 194 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,737 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-5.5:
 mysql-server-5.5 depends on mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1); however:
  Version of mysql-server-core-5.5 on system is 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to remove mysql-server but nothing happened.

Comment: Try removing `mysql-server-core-5.5`. Have you installed MySQL from anywhere other than the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: I tried but it gives me this:                                       root@me:~# apt-get -f remove mysql-server-core-5.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -f remove mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-server-5.5`

Comment: Hi I tried it but the problem is still there   root@ezzimo0s:~# sudo apt-get -f remove mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-server-5.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Then try `sudo apt-get -f remove mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server`.

Comment: Thank you Flimm. The problem is about to be solved the depending problems are solved but, when I try to install updates it gives me this msg:      <code>Requires installation of untrusted packages

The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.     wine1.5 wine1.5-i386 </code>         what can I do .

Comment: FYI, if you want to format code in comments, use backticks. See http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that you have added third party repositories or PPAs to your system improperly. If I were you, I would only install packages from the official Ubuntu repositories using the Software Centre, Synaptic or `apt-get`.

To remove third party repositories and PPAs, follow these instructions or look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

1. Open Ubuntu Software Centre.
2. Click Edit, Software Sources...
3. Click "Other Software" tab.
4. Untick all the software sources in the list.

Once you are sure this has fixed the problem, you can re-enable each repository one by one until you narrow down the problematic repository. On the command-line, you'll need to run `sudo apt-get update` after modifying the software sources list.

You probably want to take a look at `ppa-purge`. It has the added benefit that it will uninstall packages originating from the PPA as well.

In your case, you need to uninstall at least these packages:

```
 sudo apt-get -f remove mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server
```

If you find all this confusing, I recommend you go to [the Ubuntu IRC channel](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/chat) or [UbuntuForums Absolute Beginner section](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=326). AskUbuntu is designed around asking one specific question for one specific answer at a time, and may not be exactly what you're looking for in this case.